# Power BI-replacing blanks with another value

Tags: powerbi

I am new to Power BI and would like to know how to replace blank values in a table with any other value.

For eg IF (ISBLANK(TIME),TIME1,TIME) doesnot seem to work in power BI.

What is correct syntax for this.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean? Is it giving you an error? Or just not the desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try IF ( TIME, TIME1, 0 )

or

Try IF ( ISBLANK(TIME), TIME1, 0 )